# Failed Tasks on Windows 2008 R2 and Event Viewer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, task-manager

I'm trying to run a script on Windows 2008 R2 via a Task item in the Task Scheduler. It is not running. I can't figure out why. I'm looking in the event viewer and not seeing anything. Shouldn't there be some kind of error code or something? Where do I need to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the Task Scheduler log, meager though it is. Open up "Scheduled Tasks" and choose the "View Log" item in the "Advanced" menu.